# nginx proxy_pass configuration

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, proxypass

I need to proxy a couple of urls to different hosts. Actually, I'm using the same host with different port to test my nginx configuration. This is my virtual host definition:

```
server {
    listen       8081;
    server_name  domain.com;

    location /Plasmid/ {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:8000/Plasmid/;
    }


    location /_community/ {
         proxy_pass   http://localhost:8082/comments_api/ ;
    }

    location / {
        # rewrite cq_user_authenticated===(.*)/(.*)/iuuid=(.*)/commenti.html$  /Plasmid/comments/legacy/$3/$1 ;
        # rewrite querystring===(.*)$  /Plasmid/comments/legacy/$1 ;
        # rewrite cq_user_authenticated===([^&]*)&/.*uuid=([^/]*) /comments_api/legacy/$2 ;
        # rewrite userdetails(.*)  /Plasmid/comments/user_details ;
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

}
```

Of course my hosts file has mapping for the domain.com

When I call the url: http://domain.com:8081/Plasmid/default/page/12 I get an http 404

If I remove the second location from my configuration:

```
location /_community/ {
    proxy_pass   http://localhost:8082/comments_api/ ;
}
```

I get the resource I want, but some part are missed since the are hosted on a different platform:

```
[error] 1033#0: *1 open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.2.6/html/_community/content
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Do a little change:

```
location ^~ /Plasmid/ {
   proxy_pass    http://localhost:8000/Plasmid/;
}

location ^~ /_comunity/ {
   proxy_pass    http://localhost:8082/comments_api/;
```

Why is that? Because `^~` means *starts with* and when you request for page:

http://domain.com:8081/Plasmid/default/page/12

it fit to that rule. In your configuration you are using no mark and something like this:

```
location /anylocation
```

and it looks like your nginx prefer rule

```
location / {
```

than

```
location /Plasmid
```

and

```
location /_comunity
```

because it's using root directive and searching for _community/content in `html` folder (as you get in error message).

In other words `^~` has greater priority than `no mark`. One thing that could also help is to add `break` directive after each `proxy_pass` directive;